# Wireless network relay?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, home-networking, bridge

Is there hardware (links would be great) that can connect to the wireless internet already in my house and provide hard links to other hardware?

Basically the problem is that my basement is not wired up to let me hook up my cable modem. I have some electronics that do not have wireless and need a LAN wire. Is there something I could plug in downstairs to act as a relay hub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much [anything that can run](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) the excellent [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) can be setup as a wireless bridge (or repeater). But be sure to check the notes, as some of the devices require extra steps!

I've used it on the La Fonera and various D-link, Netgear and Linksys devices. The Buffalo routers also tend to work well, from what I hear. I'd just find a cheap router on newegg and see if it's compatible with DD-WRT and then setup your [wireless bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge).

There are also dedicated bridges you can buy, some go by the name of "game adapters." But they cost about as much as a DD-WRT capable router (or more) and they're not as versatile.

**edit:** see SU question: [Can I make two wireless routers communicate using the wireless?](https://superuser.com/questions/19184/can-i-make-two-wireless-routers-communicate-using-the-wireless)

Comment: Just wanted to say that I got it hooked up really easily this weekend. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be highly tempted to go with something like [this Multi-Client Bridge/AP/ WDS](http://www.solwise.co.uk/wireless-el-ncb-3220.htm) which is highly adaptable to any wireless network structure you might want to build and pretty cheap considering it's functionality.

The suggestion of DD-WRT is also a good one, though it may require slightly more setting up it's also a really cheap way of doing it - especially if you already have a spare router.

Comment: thanks, going with the other way, but gave you a +1 as well

Answer (score 0):

Apples [Airport Express](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/) is not cheap, but is by far the easiest system I've ever had to configure as a WDS Remote.  Having one upstairs and one downstairs solves your problem.  In addition, you get Airtunes and wireless USB printing as a bonus.